# REGEX to replace any type of URL

Tags: php, regex

My string is:

```
$msg = '
Here are all URLs:
------------------
google.com
www.google.com
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
ftp://ftp.google.com
';
```

I tried the following REGEX to match any type of URL and should reurn empty lines:

```
$msg = preg_replace("/^.*\b(http:\/\/)?(www\.)[^.]+\.com\b.*$/m",'',$msg);
```

### But it returns this:

```
Here are all URLs:
------------------
google.com

http://google.com

ftp://ftp.google.com
```

It means that the above REGEX is only replacing these URLs: `www.google.com` and `http://www.google.com`

Please help!

Comment: If `google.com` is a valid URL then what about `Mr.Bean` and `11.22.33.44` etc?

Comment: I meant a `URL` and NOT word or alphabets. `Mr.Bean` is NOT a `URL`

Comment: How a regex can differentiate between `abc.com` and `Mr.Bean` without checking for all possible TLD

Comment: Because URL should have .com or .org etc TLDs

Comment: @user2854563 its a huge list and probably out of scope.

Comment: **URL should have .com or .org etc TLDs** Did you forget to put this in your question?

Comment: @anubhava: there is no need to argue on this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this:

`$msg = preg_replace("/^.*\b(?:((http|ftp):\/\/)|(www\.))?[^.]+\.com\b.*$/m", "","{$msg}");`

Comment: But it don't matches up the URL if its enclosed in a TAG, e.g. `[code]www.google.com[/code]`

How to do it??

Answer (score 0):

change the regex to

```
^.*\b((http|ftp):\/\/)?((www|ftp)\.)?[^.]+\.com$
```

see how the regex matches http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/4

What you got wrong in `/^.*\b(http:\/\/)?(www\.)[^.]+\.com\b.*$`

- `www` is optional as in `google.com`

  correction added a quantifier `?` at the end of group `(www|ftp)\.)?`
- `ftp` protocal will not be matched to regex

  corrected by adding it to an alternation. `http|ftp):\/\/)?((www|ftp)\.)?`

  both the groups are optional, made by the quantifier `?` at the end
- From the examples, the strings that needs to be validated ends with `.com`. additional matching using `.*` is not required. anchore the `.com` to the end of the string using `$`. It prevents unwanted strings like `www.google.comxxxxx` from validating

Comment: I tried this: `$message = preg_replace("/^.*\b((http|ftp):\/\/)?((www|ftp)\.)?[^.]+\.com$/m", "{$error_message_link}","{$message}");` and  it only matches to `google.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?(ftp:\/\/)?.*\.com\b.*$
```

Try this.I guess you only want to remove url's.Made `www` optional as some urls are do not contain it.also added `ftp` as some urls has it..See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jI8lV7/3

Comment: I used this: `$message = preg_replace("/^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?(ftp:\/\/)?.*\.com\b.*$/gm", "{$error_message_link}","{$message}");` But it removes the entire string :(

Comment: @user2854563 you don't need to add `g` modifier. It's enabled by default in PHP.

Comment: @user2854563 What output did you expect?

Comment: @user2854563 it removes only urls as you can see in demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex : `^.*\b(?:((http|ftp):\/\/)|(www\.))?[^.]+\.com\b.*$`

[demo](http://regexr.com/39r44)

you are missing `ftp` here: `((http|ftp):\/\/)|(www\.)?` I check if there is `http` or `ftp` followed by `://` or if there's `www.`. Notice the question mark in the end of the expression which allows you to match urls such: `google.com`